# Question regarding list's append() function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a short question:

is such statement:

```
a.append(x)
x is a[-1]
```

always true?
`a` is a list, `x` can be anything (but I am particularly interested in big integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In single thread yes, they are exactly the same even the references. For multiple threads not always: `a` could be changed by other threads.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:
Yes, it must always evaluate to true